# How can I get a square matrix and put it into another matrix?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array

I need to solve this, I need to obtain the square of each element of the matrix and put it into another matrix. Both have the same n*m size.

I've already tried to multiply it with a variable that saves the value of the 
element's square.

```
int n,m,i,j;
Random rm1=new Random();
int matrix1[][]=new int[n][m];
int matrix2[][]=new int[n][m];
        for (i=0;i < matrix1.length;i++){
             for(j=0;j < matrix1[i].length;j++){
                 matrix1[i][j]=rm1.nextInt(500);
            }
        }
         for (i=0;i < matrix2.length; i++){
              for(j=0;j < matrix2[i].length;j++){
                  matrix2[i][j]=matrix1[i][j]*matrix1[i][j];               
            }
        }
System.out.println("first matrix:");
       for (i=0;i<matrix1.length;i++){          
                for (j=0;j<matrix1[i].length;j++){
                    System.out.println("("+i+","+j+")=["+matrix1[i][j]+"]");
                }
            }
 System.out.println("second matrix:");
       for (i=0;i<matrix2.length;i++){          
                for (j=0;j<matrix2[i].length;j++){
                    System.out.println("("+i+","+j+")=["+matrix2[i][j]+"]");
                }
            }
```

It doesnt give me what I want, matrix2 remains unchanged.

What I expect:(be n=m=2 and random values inside):

matrix1: `(0,0)=2 (0,1)=3 (1,0)=5 (1,1)=10`

matrix2: `(0,0)=4 (0,1)=9 (1,0)=25 (1,1)=100`

What I get:

matrix1: `(0,0)=2 (0,1)=3 (1,0)=5 (1,1)=10`

matrix2: `(0,0)=2 (0,1)=3 (1,0)=5 (1,1)=10`

Comment: What you have pasted is text rather than the exact code - you have items like "less" and "<br/>" tags which obviously would never compile.  Could you edit your question and Copy/paste the EXACT code straight from your editor (and you can use the "Code" icon to help format it)

Comment: I apologize if it was unconfortable to read, Im relatively new to the site.

Comment: no worries, but always best to start off with doing things properly.  I'm not too bothered about "difficult to read" (there are some shockers that get posted !), but rather my main concern was that little things got changed or lost (eg, if an '=' got replaced with an '==', etc), and it's those little things that might be the cause of the problem  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int n,m;
    n = 2;
    m = 3;
    int number = 0;
    int matrix1[][]=new int[n][m];
    int matrix2[][]=new int[n][m]; 

    //Fill the array one
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix1.length; j++) {
            matrix1[i][j] = (int)(10 * Math.random());
        }
    }

    //Print out first array
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix1.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matrix1[i][j] +  "  " );
        }
    }

    //Populate second array with numbers in first array
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix1.length; j++) {
            matrix2[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] * matrix1[i][j];

        }
    }


    System.out.println("Second array: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix1.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matrix2[i][j] +  "  " );
        }
    }
```

I tried to recreate your situation and it seems to work probebly, maybe there is a typo or a logic error somewhere that is causing you some problem. Trying indenting your code to organize it and make it easir to see

Comment: I just updated the code with printing features, i will try to adapt my code to what you transcribed.

Comment: it was a logic error, thanks for making it see clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `Math.pow` method.

```
matrix2[i][j] = Math.pow(matrix1[i][j], 2);
```

Comment: Tuve que convertir las matrices a Double, aun así no funcionó. :(